# JQUERY AJAX laravel 5.2 username check availability

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I want to check the availability of the username in the same page in my Registration Form in laravel 5.2. How Will i do it with Jquery AJAX. I want to check if a key is typed on the spot. I'm just a newbie. Please help?

Comment: are you going to use javasript validation rules or you want to use the laravel validation library ?

Comment: CAN I ASK FOR BOTH? So that I can use it for future references. Thanks :)

Comment: get into this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122559/laravel-5-2-talk

Comment: I am sorry, Can you please post your code for reference. You know I'm just a new to laravel and ajax. Thanks so much. I am new to this

Comment: Okay , let me share my code then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code,

Actually i did this with laravel 4.2 version but there wont't be any changes at code level  just a syntac level changes are there like  laravel 5.* uses `{{` and  `}}` brackets in blade files when larvel 5 uses `{!!` and `!}}`

Very first you will have to use the jquery validations method to validate your for, you can have a look on this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/)

This will give you better idea , that how to validate the for using jquery validations , which is so easy to use, just need to load a jquery and some validation methods thats it.

**Here is my View file :**

```
<!-- Change the "src" attribute according to your installation path -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="{{ URL::to('signup/create') }}" method="POST" class="signup-form" id='signup-form1' enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row form-div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"> <span class="skew"><span class="inside"><span class="icon-mwtMsg custum-font-icon"> </span></span></span> <span class="skew"> <span class="inside">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="regemail">
                                        </span> </span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="erroremail register-error-block"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"> <span class="skew"><span class="inside"><span class="icon-mwtTag custum-font-icon"> </span></span></span> <span class="skew"> <span class="inside">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Gamer Tag" name="gamertag" id="gamertag">
                                        </span> </span> 
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="errortag register-error-block"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Create-account-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-skew btn-red" type="submit" name="register" id="register-btn"><span>Create Account</span></button>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

Now add the jquery validation for this sign up form

```
$("#signup-form1").validate({
                    errorElement : 'div',
                    errorLabelContainer: '.errorTxt',
                    ignore: [],
                    rules: {
                        email:{
                            required:true, 
                            email:true,
                            remote: {
                                url: "signup/checkemail",
                                type: "post",
                                data: {email: $("input[email='email']").val(), _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                                dataFilter: function (data) {
                                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                                    if (json.msg == "true") {
                                        return "\"" + "Email address already in use" + "\"";
                                    } else {
                                        return 'true';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        gamertag: {
                            required: true,
                            alphanumeric:true
                        },
                    },
                    messages: {
                        email: {
                            required: "Email address is required.",
                            email: "Please enter valid email address.",
                            remote: "Email address already in use!"
                        },
                        gamertag: {
                            required: "Gamer Tag is required.",
                            alphanumeric: "Gamer Tag must contain alphanumeric string."
                        }
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        //$(element).closest('.skew').append()
                        if (element.attr("name") == "email" ) {
                            $(".erroremail").append(error);
                        }
                        else if (element.attr("name") == "gamertag" ) {
                            $(".errortag").append(error);
                        }
                        else {
                                  error.append($('.errorTxt span'));
                        }
                    },
                    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit       

                    },
                    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                        $(element).closest('.skew').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
                    },
                    unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                        $(element).closest('.skew').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
                    },
                    success: function (label) {
                        label.closest('.skew').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        //console.log(form);
                        $("#signup-form1").submit();
                        // Adding a New Post
                    }
                });
```

In above script if you have noticed then i have used `remote: { }` method what it does is it also check with th ajax call if the given email if exists in the database or not .

and to perform that i did some code in my controller which is some thing like this

**Here is my Controller function** to check if email is exists or not.

```
public function postCheckemail(){
      //$user = Register::where('email', Input::get('email'))->get();
      $user = DB::table('users')->where('email', Input::get('email'));
        if($user->count()) {
            return Response::json(array('msg' => 'true'));
        }
        return Response::json(array('msg' => 'false'));  
    }
```

Which is going to return the message with true and false in json format.

This was with the ajax,

Now if you dont want this jquery validations method then you can use the validation feature given by laravel itself [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

Let say this is your **View File** :

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('signup/create') }}" method="POST" class="signup-form" id='signup-form1' enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row form-div">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"> <span class="skew"><span class="inside"><span class="icon-mwtMsg custum-font-icon"> </span></span></span> <span class="skew"> <span class="inside">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="regemail">
                                        </span> </span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="erroremail register-error-block"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group"> <span class="skew"><span class="inside"><span class="icon-mwtTag custum-font-icon"> </span></span></span> <span class="skew"> <span class="inside">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Gamer Tag" name="gamertag" id="gamertag">
                                        </span> </span> 
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="errortag register-error-block"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Create-account-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-skew btn-red" type="submit" name="register" id="register-btn"><span>Create Account</span></button>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

And here is you **Controller** function to validate it.

```
public function postCreate(){
        $validator = Validator::make(array(
                'email' => Input::get( 'email' ),
                'gamertag' => Input::get( 'gamertag' ),
            ),      
            array(              
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'gamertag' => 'required|min:3'
            ));

            if ($validator->fails())
            {       
                $messages = $validator->messages()->first();            
                //return Redirect::to('signup')->with('error_message', $messages);
                $data['success'] = false;    
                $data['message'] = $messages;
            }
            else
            {           
                //Your insert Query here to store the data in database 
            }

            return Response::json($data);
    }
```

Thats it!

Do not hesitate to ask me again if you stuck anywhere anytime.

Comment: Thank you sir, You are brilliant, Indians are really great :)

Comment: How About the your routes file in these sir? What is this  url: "signup/checkemail",??

Comment: **Route::controller('signup', 'SignupController');**

What this will do is .write signup in the url and it will automatically call the index function of the signup controller and by `signup/myFunctionNam`  you can each an every function of the controller.    checkemail  is my function here in the controller file.  i wanted to call the function `checkemail` that is why i have written `url: "signup/checkemail",`  in the remote URL of the jquery validation,

Comment: the signup/checkemail is a Get or POST Request?

Comment: Oh it's post Request i forgot hihi

Comment: in laravel there is feature that you can define it when you are declaring a function  like if you are writing  `public  function getMyfunction { }` then it will be consider as GET method and if you write `postMyfunction ` then it is function with POST method.  by default it uses GET.   and declaring functions this way you dont need to mention it routes. That is the advantage.

Comment: Thanks so much, my friend. May God bless you more.